# Probability that a random bridge board does not contain a sequence?

Tags: probability-theory, card-games

Two cards with adjacent values and the same suit produce a SEQUENCE. For example,
the heart-ten and the heart-jack form a sequence. The order of the values in
bridge is $$23456789TJQKA$$

-What is the probability that a random bridge board contains no sequence in any
 hand ? (That means, for example : If North holds the queen of spades, he neither
 holds the jack nor the king of spades )

A long time ago, I approached this problem by first determining all possible
combinations not containing a sequence (for example kt742) , and then calculate
the number of boards from that. I remember that the probability is very low.
But there should be a better method, perhaps inclusion-exclusion or something
like that.

Comment: $A-2$ in the same suit is NOT considered as a sequence.

Comment: Please clarify: A fixed hand contains at least one sequence or any of the four hand countain at least one sequence? Also note that a ten is usually writen as `X` if only one letter is available (roman numeral), but that's just a style remark.

Comment: @AlexR: I've usually seen T, not X.  So I think it is just a (UK/US) style remark. :-)

Comment: The desired event : None of the four hands contains a sequence. Or, the oppositive event : Some hand contains at least one sequence.

Comment: @Peter Allright, I slightly changed the wording to make this point clear. I hope you don't mind :)

Comment: A very crude upper bound, obtained by ignoring the fact that the hands must all have the same number of cards, is

$$
\frac{4^4\cdot3^{48}}{\binom{52}{13,13,13,13}}\approx0.0004\;.
$$

Comment: @Alex No, I do not :)

Comment: @joriki how did you come to this bound ?

Comment: Distribute the aces ($4^4$). Then distribute the kings, queens, etc. -- each time you have $3$ choices to avoid creating a sequence. That gives a total of $4^4\cdot3^{48}$ ways of distributing the cards. That's way too many, since it doesn't take into account that each hand must have $13$ cards, but it's still good enough to get a bound.

Comment: @joriki a good start, as it shows that the probability is indeed very low.

Comment: If we consider the events of the sequences not occurring as approximately independent, the probability becomes $(3/4)^{48}$ (as there are $48$ potential sequences). This is about $10^{-6}$. A computer simulation yields roughly $2.6\cdot10^{-6}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first calculate, for each club distribution $(n_n,n_s,n_e,n_w)$ *distinguishing players but not ranks*, how many explicit (distinguishing ranks too) distributions $c$ there are with no player having consecutive clubs. There are $4\cdot3^{12}$ explicit distributions in all, small enough to loop over and tabulate. Then associate with $(n_n,n_s,n_e,n_w)$ the monomial $cw^{n_n}x^{n_s}y^{n_e}z^{n_w}$:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from math import factorial
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product, accumulate, permutations

distribs = Counter()
for diffs in product(*([(0,1,2,3)] + [(1,2,3)]*12)):
    dist = list(accumulate(diffs, lambda x,y: (x+y)%4))
    dist = tuple(dist.count(i) for i in (0,1,2,3))
    distribs[dist] += 1
print(distribs)
for (d, c) in distribs.items():
    l = f"+{c}" + "".join(f"{v}{p if p > 1 else ''}" for (v, p) in zip("wxyz", d) if p > 0)
    print(l, end="")
print()
```

The sum of monomials is the generating polynomial for admissible club distributions. The $w^{13}x^{13}y^{13}z^{13}$ coefficient of the fourth power of this polynomial is then the number of bridge deals where nobody has a sequence, and it is $141134095290429908002008$. The corresponding probability is then this number divided by $\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}$, approximately $2.631\cdot10^{-6}$.

Answer (score -2):

if i get your question right,
an ideal sample set E will be a set of all subsets
E={S2,S3,S4,…,S12}

whereas is subset of three serial number s=[n-1,n,n+1]

your sample space for all possible options are equal 2^11 
one of these event meet the required criteria which is  ‘E' in your case.
the probability of having Pr(E=1) = 1/(2^11)

hope it helps